# Android KitKat Bug With Default Browser Actions

Tags: browser, 4.4-kitkat, youtube, streaming

I'm having a problem with my nexus 5 and I'm getting mad: I installed *Dice player* as usual, after a factory reset, but *Dolphin browser* doesn't ask me which app should it use to play videos (from mobile youtube or other sites).

How can I reset the default app? I tried to look into settings-app-reset to default but nothing. It won't ask me to use another app, it just opens stock browser player. I tried other browsers too but no luck. Tried resetting app preferences but nothing.

I updated to 4.4.2 thinking the issue was solved but again, same problem. I did a full wipe, tried stock ROM and then Purity ROM, different kernels but no luck.

Am I the only one having this issue? Could you try to reproduce it for me?

Steps:

1. install a browser (dolphin browser or chrome in my case)
2. install dice player (or MX Player if it gets updated)
3. open youtube (or any site with video files) from browser and open a video. see if it asks to play it with dice player or it just opens stock browser player

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stock browser player"? Do you mean the video opens in Dolphin?

Comment: Yes, it opens in Dolphin without asking me if I want to play the video in another player (dice player or MX player)..

Answer (score 1):

This could just be a shortcoming in Dolphin. It's up to the app to decide if it wants to open a new URL itself, or offer it to other apps. Last year, Firefox had a similar problem, that it wouldn't ever offer a *chooser* when you clicked on a link in Firefox. Even a link to a YouTube video would open the mobile interface in Firefox instead of offering to open the YouTube app.

From your description, it sounds like Dolphin has the same problem. (I don't have Dolphin to test this myself.) You should report it to the developers and ask them to offer video links to other apps. At least they should be able to confirm whether this is what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Nexus 5 with Kikat 4.4.2

Try this:

1. Setting>Apps
2. Select the 'blank app'
3. Scroll down until you see a button 'Clear defaults'
4. Click 'Clear defaults'

That how I switch between Chrome and Chrome Beta browser. Hope this help

Comment: That would help if the user had selected a default app. But the described issue is rather a bug, where this doesn't help (should be fixed meanwhile with 4.2.2). Still, your answer could be helpful for those where it's not the bug, but an accidental "always use" hit :)

Answer (score -1):

Touch&hold on the video until a menu opens and at the bottom you will see something like open with an app - And thats your prompt ... select your player and have fun ... :DD

Answer (score -1):

Go to task manager and select the defaults tab then select clear defaults.  Find the app you need to change then clear the defaults for that app.  Next time it should ask you.

Comment: That's a good guess, but it's the same suggestion as one of the other answers. Izzy already explained why that won't help in this case.